# Web2py forms is default table

Tags: web2py

When we define form in `web2py` , (like form = `SQLFORM.factory()`), it shows as a `table`. 
How to change it to `div`, so that doing CSS is easy

Comment: HTML entities highlighted as code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SQLFORM` takes a `formstyle` argument. There are several built-in formstyles that can be specified, or you can provide your own custom formstyle function. For a fairly generic div-based layout, you can do:

```
form = SQLFORM(..., formstyle='divs')
```

For more details, see the relevant section of the [documentation](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#SQLFORM).

You can also create a [custom form layout](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#Custom-forms) in the view.